# create SQL table w/o duplicate the same column

Tags: sql, database-design, datatable

I've this excel table

[image: excel table]

[image]

I want to create a sql table and when I run queries on it I get something similar to the excel table.

at first I thought about this table

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table_1
(
id_course nchar(10) NOT NULL,
car nchar(10) NOT NULL
local nchar(10) NOT NULL,
arrival_time time(7) NOT NULL,
direction nchar(10) NOT NULL,
)  ON [PRIMARY]
```

but I noticed that if I do the same I will probably have repetitions of the column car and id_course, because for each of them I have several locals browsed.

in this case I thought about this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table_1
(
id_course nchar(10) NOT NULL,
car nchar(10) NOT NULL
local1 nchar(10) NOT NULL,
local2 nchar(10) NOT NULL,
local3 nchar(10) NOT NULL
.
.
local8 nchar(10) NOT NULL,
direction nchar(10) NOT NULL
)  ON [PRIMARY]
```

and in the localX column I put the arrival time. what do you think ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because has a question in image rather than the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should practice DB table normalization here.
Your tables should be `CarCourse` and `CarLocalData`

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CarCourse
(
CourseId nchar(10) IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
car nchar(10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_CarCourse_CourseId  PRIMARY KEY(CourseId)

)  
CREATE TABLE dbo.CarLocalData
(
CourseId nchar(10) NOT NULL,
local nchar(10) NOT NULL,
arrival_time time(7) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_CarLocalData_CourseId  FOREIGN KEY (CourseId ) REFERENCES dbo.[CarCourse](id_course)
)
```